Infinite force paradox in pulling a car out of mud
Consider a car stuck in mud. A way to pull the car out would be tying a rope with a tree and pulling on the rope perpendicularly, at the midpoint:

This works well as it magnifies the force depending on the extent to which you have pulled the rope (the angle of the V-shape formed). The proof:

If $L\gg d$, then $T\gg F$.
But if $d\to 0$, this would imply that an infinite force would act on the tree and the car. Wouldn't the tree collapse in such a situation, by a minimal force acting at the midpoint?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

All the equation $$T = \frac{F l}{2d}$$
is telling you, is that you require a infinite tension in the rope to make sure that a non-zero force applied to it results in zero deflection.
If the orthogonal force is zero, and d =0 then the equation becomes $T = 0/0$ which is undefined, not infinite.

But if d→0, this would imply that an infinite force would act on the
tree and the car. Wouldn't the tree collapse in such a situation, by a
minimal force acting at the midpoint?

Something to consider. No rope is infinitely rigid. They stretch and the more they stretch the greater the deflection (d) becomes which attenuates the build up of tension.
If the amount a rope stretches is defined as  ($\Delta L$) the tension in the rope is given as:
$$ T = \frac{\Delta L}{L} \times A E$$
where A is the cross sectional area of the rope and E is the modulus of elasticity of the rope. See Wikipedia: Hooke's Law.

Using the diagram and Pythagoras:
$$(L + \Delta L)/2 = \sqrt{(L/2)^2 + d^2}  $$ a
$$\rightarrow \ \Delta L = \sqrt{L^2 + 4 d^2} - L$$
Substitute this equation for $\Delta L$ into the alternative equation for tension given above:
$$ T = \frac{\sqrt{L^2 + 4d^2} - L}{L} \times A E$$
and it now becomes clear that when the elasticity of the rope is taken into account, that d is not independent of the applied orthogonal force and that the tension goes to zero as d goes to zero. The greater the tension, the greater d becomes, so the original equation is prevented from going to infinity when real world elasticity is taken into account.
Using the first definition of tension As $T = FL/(2 \cos \theta)$ and substituting $\cos \theta = d/(L+\Delta L)$ and using the equation for $\Delta L$ derived using Pythagoras above, we can obtain an equation for the force that is also function of d:
$$F = 2T \frac{d}{(L+ \Delta L)} = \frac{2AE\Delta L d}{L(L+\Delta L)}$$
Here is a table of Tension and Force values for various value of d, assuming a 100m long steel cable:

It can be seen that the mechanical advantage is indeed huge for d = 0.1 metres but the corresponding tension is too small to be of any practical use here. For a 2,000 Kg car it would require somewhere in the ball park of around 10,000 to 20,000 Newtons to get it moving. This would require d to be around 30 to 40 metres and at value the mechanical advantage is somewhere between 2 and 1.6 which is not huge, but not to be sneezed at. Tying a rope to the centre of the first one and looping it around another tree that is located orthogonally to the first rope, would help significantly, due to the mechanical advantage of a pulley set up.

Do you think d=0 is a very absurd case because that way we are applying force on rope perpendicular to it such way that the rope does not bend. That is not possible. So can we apply this reasoning to rule out d=0 case?

@Proscionexium The fact that the theoretical result is infinite is indeed a reflection of the absurdity.

You can never have $d=0$ in real life because every rope is elastic and as soon as you start to apply a force on it it will deflect causing $d>0$
Applying equations in Physics always involves a certain level of idealization which means there are assumptions and limits on how to apply said laws.
Here you have a situation where the idealization leads to a singularity when $d=0$, as there is nothing resisting the perpendicular force in this configuration which leads to applying a force against a massless rope.

A valid point. That was what I thought. A force perpendicular to rope and still rope being straight must mean the whole rope is translating but its tied in this case. Quite a contradiction.

Getting a good equation in physics always involves some simplifying assumptions. When you see infinities, the first thing to do is to check your simplifying assumptions and see if they still hold.
The first simplifying assumption is that the rope is inextensible. That is a reasonable assumption at typical angles because the changes in length of the rope are small compared to the other distances. However, specifically when looking at $d=0$ even small changes in length will now be large compared to changes in $d$. So the rope would need to be treated as being extensible.
Another assumption is that the rope is massless. This is important because it means that the catenary deflection is negligible. Again, negligible is compared to the other distances, which will no longer be valid for $d=0$.
Another assumption is that the tree is rigid. As anyone with experience can tell you, trees are not rigid. And particularly not as the forces become large. It is indeed possible to provide enough mechanical advantage to bend, break, or uproot a tree.
I am sure that there are other assumptions that break down, but the point is that any one of these assumptions will prevent the infinity from happening. They are fine assumptions, but they limit the validity of the solution. The infinity is not something real in this case, but a hint from the math that an assumption is failing there.

Re, "It is...possible to...bend, break, or uproot a tree." And, the exact thing that the OP is trying to understand is why then, is the tree not bent, broken, or uprooted before the car starts to move or the rope starts to stretch.

@SolomonSlow which was also covered in the previous 3 paragraphs. The violation of any of these assumptions is sufficient

@SolomonSlow You are the OP, aren't you?

@my2cts no they are not. Why do you think so?
